# How to fetch and edit/update all the data comes from Database in Bootstrap Modal Popup, even my Fetch Data Table is CONCATENATED?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

### I have a problem in Fetching all the Data by its ID coming from Database in Bootstrap Modal Popup.

I have a Fetch Table in my Program. This is my code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">

                    <?php
                      require_once("include/connect.php"); //To connect Database


                      try{
                          $sql="SELECT patient_id, CONCAT(patient_lname, ', ', patient_fname, ' ', patient_mi) AS Fullname, age, gender, status, address FROM tbl_patientinfo ORDER BY patient_lname";  //Patient Name is CONCATENATED (Fullname)
                          $result=$con->prepare($sql);
                          $result->execute();
                    ?>

                      <table class="table table-hover" id="table-1">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">
                              #
                            </th>
                            <th>Patient Name</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        <?php while($row=$result->fetch()){ ?>
                          <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['patient_id']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['Fullname']; ?></td> //Concatenated Last Name, First Name, and MI
                            <td><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                            <a href="#editpatient" class="edit-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editpatient"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button></a>  //Modal Button
                          </td>
                          </tr>

                          <?php } ?>

                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                      
                      <?php
                        } catch (PDOException $th){
                          echo "Error: ".$th->getMessage();
                        }

                        $con=null;
                      ?>

                    </div>
```

I want to fetch all the data from the Database (written in my `$sql` on the codes above) in Bootstrap Modal Popup using **Javascript or JQuery** code. This is my code in Javascript or JQuery:

```
<!-- SCRIPT FOR FETCH RECORD IN MODAL -->  
<script> 
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.edit-btn').on('click', function () {
            $('#editpatient').modal('show');
    
                $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    
                var data = $tr.children("td").map(function () {
                    return $(this).text();
                }).get();
    
                console.log(data);
    
                $('#patient_id').val(data[0]);
                $('#patient_lname').val(data[1]);
                $('#patient_fname').val(data[2]);
                $('#patient_mi').val(data[3]);
                $('#dob').val(data[4]);
                $('#age').val(data[5]);
                $('#gender').val(data[6]);
                $('#status').val(data[7]);
                $('#address').val(data[8]);
                $('#cnum').val(data[9]);
                $('#company').val(data[10]);    
        }); }); 
</script> 
<!-- END OF SCRIPT FOR FETCH RECORD IN MODAL -->
```

And this is my Codes in Modal:

```
<!-- EDIT MODAL PATIENT -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="editpatient" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="formModal"
          aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="formModal">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="">
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <form method="POST" action="save-patient.php">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt-patient_id" id="patient_id" placeholder="ID">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Last Name</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <div class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt-patient_lname" id="patient_lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>First Name</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <div class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt-patient_fname" id="patient_fname" placeholder="First Name" required="true">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Middle Name</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <div class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt-patient_mi" id="patient_mi" placeholder="Middle Name">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Date Picker</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="txt-dob" id="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" required="true">
                          </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Age</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <div class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt-age" id="age" placeholder="Age" required="true">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Gender</label>
                          <select class="form-control" name="txt-gender" id="gender" required="true">
                            <option value="" readonly>--- Please Select ---</option>
                            <option value="Male">MALE</option>
                            <option value="Female">FEMALE</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Civil Status</label>
                          <select class="form-control" name="txt-status" id="status" required="true">
                          <option value="" readonly>--- Please Select ---</option>
                            <option>Single</option>
                            <option>Married</option>
                            <option>Widowed</option>
                            <option>Separated</option>
                            <option>Divorced</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Address</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <div class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt-address" id="address" required="true">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Contact Number</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <div class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt-cnum"  id="cnum" required="true">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Company(Optional)</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <div class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-building"></i>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt-company" id="company">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of EDIT MODAL PATIENT -->
```

**My Problem is I want to fetch all data coming from database (means, not concatenated) by its ID but when the Modal shows, the data shows a concatenated data coming from the FETCH DATA TABLE.**
[This is my sample FETCH DATA TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGLMK.png)

[And this is my Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvfYb.png)

Please help me to fix my problem. I already do this a month ago and until now, I can't solve this problem. I'm still new in this Programming Languages. I need help from others like you Guys. I hope you everybody can help me to fix this. Thank you so much <3